# Can't set state data fetched from Firestore to render()

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to fetch some data with Firestore, and then these data should be set up to `this.setState()`. But this can't be rendered.

My code:

```
class Item extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       item: null,
    }

    let self = this;
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("items")
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then(function(doc) {
        self.setState({
          item: doc.data()
        });
      });
  }
}

render() {
  console.log("item", this.state.item);
  // null
  return(
    <p>{item.name}</p>
  )
}
```

I have tried to set up `firebase()` in `componentDidMount()`. But it failed...

And I tried to update Firebase code like below, but it failed.

```
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("items")
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          self.setState({ item: doc.data() });
        });
      });
```

Comment: U should use `componentDidMount` and also after `then` you should add `catch` to see if it throw any error

Comment: problem solved ???

Comment: @RajanLagah Thank you so much, I'll try to add it.

Comment: @PrakashKarena Thanks! I really appreciate your help but I could not have it done. So I'm trying to consider another way.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.setState({
          room: doc.data()
        });
```

in above code you are not updating item. may be modify this as following ?

```
self.setState({
              item: doc.data()// or any value using doc as per your needs
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getDerivedStateFromProps = (props, state) =>  {
const { id } = props.match.params;
if(id){
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("items")
  .doc(id)
  .get()
  .then(function(doc) {
    this.setState({
      item : doc.data()  // use item here 
    });
  })
  .catch(err=>console.log(err))
 }
}
```

Comment: He stated that he already use `componentDidMount` and failed.

Comment: @RajanLagah Lagah if he get id from props then and then request will be send to firebase

Comment: Thank you so much!! I really appreciate your help, it's still a problem. But I'm trying to solve it moer.